# How add Border to Flex charts?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Im trying to add border like in the image to flex charts. I used vertical and horizontal Axis renderers but that method id not proper solution. Guys do you have any idea to achieve this one?

[image: How add border like this to flex charts ?]

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside a canvas and give it that colour and required padding.